# does code check every if statement?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, performance, if-statement

So i was practicing on past google code jam problems(btw it is on 7th april if you don't already know) and i wrote this code in which i put multiple if statements.
Looks something like this:

```
for(int b=0;b<length;b++)
                        {
                           if(array[b]==1 && done1==false)
                           {
                              done1=true;

                           }

                           if(array[b]==2 && done2==false)
                           {
                              done2=true;
                           }

                             if(array[b]==3 && done3==false)
                           {
                              done3=true;
                           }

                           if(array[b]==4 && done4==false)
                           {
                              done4=true;
                           }

                           if(array[b]==5 && done5==false)
                           {
                              done5=true;
                           }

                           if(array[b]==6 && done6==false)
                           {
                              done6=true;
                           }

                           if(array[b]==7 && done7==false)
                           {
                              done7=true;

                           }

                           if(array[b]==8 && done8==false)
                           {
                              done8=true;

                           }

                           if(array[b]==9 && done9==false)
                           {
                              done9=true;

                           }

                           if(array[b]==0 && done0==false)
                           {
                              done0=true;

                           }

                           if(done0==true && done1==true && done2==true && done3==true && done4==true && done5==true && done6==true && done7==true && done8==true && done9==true)
                           {
                               System.out.println("Case"+" "+"#"+(K-T) + ":"+G);
                               break;
                           }



}
```

My question is does it check every 'if' statement or only till the first 'if' which satisfies the condition.Also is it bad if i write if statements like this?
Any help is appreciated.Sorry if this is way too noob a question for you

Do let me know if you need more details.Thanks!

EDIT:
Everyone seems to have the impression that i need the program to get out of the loop once the condition is fulfilled. I don't. I want it to check every condition and act accordingly.
For context:
there is a number N and i need to check if N,2N,3N.... contains all the digits and print the last number which will complete the set of digits.So I separate the digits and put them in an array and check with the `for loop` .

Lastly I'm sorry for not debugging. I'm a beginner and i thought I'd just ask the pros.

Comment: why don't you debug it and see?  You will learn a lot more from experience rather than by asking

Comment: Use the debugger built into your IDE to step through the code and see. Using a debugger is **not** an advanced skill; it's a fundamental skill beginners need, early, so they can explore questions like this. Separately: Refer to tutorials to get further insight into how `if` works.

Comment: thanks @T.J.Crowder  i'll try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't used `else` or `continue` or `break` or something else to prevent control from flowing to the next `if` after a previous one, each of those is evaluated.

Simpler case:

```
if (condition1) {
    System.out.println("Condition1");
}
if (condition2) {
    System.out.println("Condition2");
}
```

The second `if` is not in any way affected by the first one (unless the first one causes an exception to be thrown). But:

```
if (condition1) {
    System.out.println("Condition1");
}
else if (condition2) {
    System.out.println("Condition2");
}
```

Now the second `if` is part of the first `if`'s `else` clause, so it's only evaluated if the first `if`'s condition was false.

Your code is in a loop, so another example of interrupting the normal flow of control:

```
for (/*....*/) {
    if (condition1) {
        System.out.println("Condition1");
        continue;
    }
    if (condition2) {
        System.out.println("Condition2");
    }
}
```

There, since the first `if`'s block contains `continue`, which jumps to the end of the loop iteration and starts the next, if the first `if`'s condition is true, we end up skipping the second. (The same would be true of `break`.)

I suggest using the debugger built into your IDE to step through the code and see how this stuff works. Using a debugger is **not** an advanced skill; it's a fundamental skill beginners need, early, so they can explore questions like this. Additionally, I suggest reading through some tutorials and/or Java books to understand the basics of flow control.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Did you at least debug it to answer your question?
There's a difference between `if` vs `if-else` statement. If-else will go though all the conditions and will check until it find the condition to be `true`. On the other hand multiple if's statement will be check by the program regardless if one or all are true.

Answer (score 0):

You have individual if statements so it will execute each if statement.
If you used something like if-then-else statements, it will execute until a if statement is true and then exit. 
Check this link on if-then and if-then-else statements: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 0):

you must put `else if(array[b]==2&&done2=false)` in your problem because you are comparing only one array down to `else if(array[b]==0&&done0=false)`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes, every if statement will be tested each time through the loop regardless of the results of any prior if test.

Your second question cannot be answered in the abstract context presented. Moreover, I believe the question asks for an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, it will check every if statements. The reason is simple, you are not breaking out of the loop after a condition is evaluated to true.

If you want to break out of the loop after a condition evaluates to true, you should write:

```
if(array[b]==1 && done1==false)
{
  done1=true;
  break; // or continue; if you want to continue on to the next loop
}
```

On another note, your code seems overly complicated. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

as the different if statements are not related to each other, all the if statements will be checked.